# Newton's law of cooling without data?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, cooling, liquid-state

I am wondering if it is possible to find the time it takes for a cup of tea to cool down if you know only the initial temperature of the tea and the point where you decide that the cup has cooled down?

For example, initial: 75˚C   Cool: from 27˚C     Room Temperature 25˚C

Is it possible to use this formula?

Q = h x A x (T-Ta)
if I know the values for h, A, T, and Ta?

I also know the volume used.
Is there a formula to find the time for cool down?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

At a very minimum, you will need to add volume to the list of things you need to know.  It's easy to see that a bowl of tea cools slower than a thimble full, despite more heat leaving the bowl every second.  It's just so much larger!

You can probably make some first order guesses with $\dot Q=hA(T-T_a)$.  But you're going to run into problems because tea is a liquid.  Convection is a *major* player in how tea cools.  The equations for how fast convection affects things are much more complicated than those governing the cooling of a simple solid slab.

To make an extreme example, if I installed a series of horizontal baffles in the tea, preventing it from forming convection cells, it would cool *much much* more slowly.  Obviously tea cups don't normally come with such baffles, but it shows how important the convection is in this scenario.

All of these affect $h$.  $h$ will vary over time based on these effects.  There are [tabulated heat transfer coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_transfer_coefficient) that you can use, but most of them are designed around continuous heat exchanges, where the temperature gradients are well behaved and not changing rapidly.  In your case, as the temperature cools, you'll find weaker convection cells, so $h$ will decrease.

Comment: Suggested edit: $Q$ to $\dot Q$ or $\dfrac {d}{dt} Q$

Comment: @gs Thanks.  Fixed!